# How to convert a JSON object (created by jquery-css-parser) back to valid CSS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, parsing

We are currently using the following jQuery plugin on our project to parse CSS to a JSON object.

http://bililite.com/blog/2009/01/16/jquery-css-parser/#parserdetails

We now require to parse back the JSON object to CSS ("as a string") as well.

I couldn't find a way to parse back from a JSON object to CSS using this plugin. It parses the CSS to JSON great, and the structure it uses is just what we need, but we also need a way to parse back the JSON object to CSS.

Is there any possible solution that can parse back the JSON object that this plugin generates back to CSS ?

Example JSON object to deserialize:

```
{
  'div div:first' : {
    'font-weight' : 'bold',
    'color': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'
  },
  'div > span' : {
    'color': 'red'
  }
}
```

Further info:
I may be missing a feature of this plugin that does just that, but I did look quite closely at the docs.

I also came across this plugin that parses to JSON and back, but the JSON format is wayyy too off from the one we are currently using.  https://github.com/aramk/CSSJSON

Comment: When you say "parse back into CSS" do you mean generating the actual CSS markup as a string, or applying the style to an HTML element?

Comment: We need to generate back the CSS (as a string) from the JSON object. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Oh ... sorry for that ... I guess I'll rephrase. I need a solution to this issue I'm facing. I need to convert back the object that this jQuery CSS Parser plugin generates into valid CSS code.

Comment: I tried a couple of plugins, and tried to iterate through the object extracting keys and values, but I'm a newbie at js / jquery and my code looks like junk, it didn't work well either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cssString = "";

// cssJSON would be the JavaScript object representing your CSS.
for (var objKey in cssJSON) {

    // objKey is the name of the key in the JavaScript object.
    // In this case, it's also the CSS selector.
    cssString += objKey + " {";

    var cssProperties = cssJSON[objKey];
    for (var cssPropertyName in cssProperties) {
        cssString += cssPropertyName + ": " + cssProperties[cssPropertyName] + ";";
    }

    cssString += "}";
}
```

Be advised: I have not tested this code, so please use at your own risk. There may be some edge cases that this doesn't account for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [JavaScript CSS Parser](http://www.glazman.org/JSCSSP/) can help you

The tool itself is pretty easy,

Suppose you have your whole CSS as a string **cssString**:

```
var parser = new CSSParser();
var serialized = parser.parse(cssString, false, true);
```

This will generate the Json serializable object of your CSS Style sheet.

You can now iterate all your css rules, and inspect them:

```
var firstRule = serialized.cssRules[0]; //Returns the first css rule you defined
var thirdDeclaration = firstRule.declarations[2]; //Returns the third declaration of your first css rule
console.log(thirdDeclaration.property); //Prints out the value
```

So, for example, if you serialized this string:

```
body {
   color: black;
   width: 50px;
   height: 70px;
   text-align: center;
}

p {
   color: red;
}
```

The above code would print out **70px**, which is the property value of the third declaration (**height**) of the first defined css rule (**body**)

I guess you can perform some logic to iterate over all your serialized CSS Json object, and deserialize it into a CSS File, or add the rules to your HTML tags at runtime, anyways you have all the information you need about the CSS rules.

I hope this helped you!

**PS: Best of all, it doesn't need jQuery! :D (Nothing happens if you use it, though)**